# ¿Como puedo detener una ejecución de java especifica a través del cmd de windows 10?

Tags: cmd

tengo esa duda como puedo matar una ejecución especifica de java a través de comandos windows, se que existe el "taskkill /f /im java.exe" pero ese comando mata a todos los java que se están ejecutando en ese instante y en este caso yo quiero forzar o matar el proceso de una librería por ejemplo de un archivo .jar se que se llama "abcd.jar(libreria java)". Espero me puedan ayudar me seria de mucha ayuda. Gracias. :'c

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para así poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Puedes intentar lo de esta respuesta en SuperUser? https://superuser.com/questions/877346/how-to-kill-a-specific-java-process-by-application-name